# In this code, even if I enter First side : 3, Second side: 3, Third side: 3, it should show the result as "equilateral" but it showing "isosceles"

Tags: c

In this code, even if I enter "First side : 3", "Second side: 3", "Third side: 3", it should show the result as "equilateral" but it shows "isosceles".

The output is like this:

Enter first side: 3

Enter second side: 3

Enter third side: 3

The triangle is isosceles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
int b;
int c;

    printf("Enter first side: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        
    printf("Enter second side: ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        
    printf("Enter third side: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        
    if (a+b>c && b+c>a && c+a>b)
    {
        if (a==b==c)
        {
            printf("The triangle is equilateral.");
        }
    
        else if (a==b || b==c || c==a)
        {
            printf("The triangle is isosceles.");
        }
    
        else
        {
            printf("The triangle is scalene.");
        }
    }
    
    else
    {
        printf("Triangle is not valid.");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what `a==b==c` actually means. You can rewrite it as `(a==b)==c`.

Comment: I tried (a==b)==c, but the output is same.

Comment: I think @ThomasJager was saying the code is wrong. Use `&&` instead

Comment: @BarryCarter can you please tell me what's wrong with this code `a==b==c`?

Comment: It's asking `(a==b)==c`. If `a` and `b` are equal then `a==b` is 1, otherwise it's 0. Therefore, you're checking if c is equal to 0 or 1, which is not what you want

Comment: So you need a==b && a==c to ensure they are all equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are correct, but I thought I would take your code and add a few "printf" statements to illustrate what was happening in the statement "if (a==b==c)".

Here are some lines of code I added just prior to the tests.

```
        printf("a==b equates to: %d\n", (a==b));

        printf("1==c equates to 1==%d which is %d\n",c, (1==c));

        printf("So, a==b==c equates to: %d\n", (a==b==c));
```

The testing in your clause is moving from left to right, starting with the test "a==b".  That is indeed true so the result of that test is going to be true or in the case of "C" a value of "1".  So next, that result will be compared to the value of "c" which equates to literal value of "1" being equal to "c" (1==c).  Unless the enter side lengths were all "1", this portion of the test will equate to "false" or in the case of "C" a value of "0".  This test proved out when running your program with the additional print statements.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Triangles/bin/Release$ ./Triangles 
Enter first side: 3
Enter second side: 3
Enter third side: 3
a==b equates to: 1
1==c equates to 1==3 which is 0
So, a==b==c equates to: 0
The triangle is isosceles.
```

So, as noted, "aa==bb==cc" does not qualify as a shortcut for the type of test you want to do.  Your if statement should be:

```
if ((a==b) && (b==c))
```

as noted in the comments.

Hopefully, that should clarify things.

Comment: Thank you @NoDakker, I understand that very clearly now.